# Unexplainable, unmeasurable lag, StopWatch issue

Tags: c#, for-loop, xna, lag, stopwatch

I recently made some major optimizations to a certain method that returns the value of a block at a position:

```
public int blockGet(x, y, layer)
```

I use this method in a lot of places, including this method, which draws blocks in an area:

```
public void DrawBlock()
{
    Stopwatch swblock = new Stopwatch(); swblock.Start();

    //Set variables
    Color drawColor = Color.White;
    for (int x = viewbX - 1; x < viewbX + viewWidth; x ++)
    {
        for (int y = viewbY - 1; y < viewbY + viewHeight; y ++)
        {
            //Update
            #region Variables
            int blockBG = blockGet(x, y, layerBG);
            int blockBG2 = blockGet(x, y, layerBG2);
            int blockFG = blockGet(x, y, layerFG);
            int blockFG2 = blockGet(x, y, layerFG2);
            Rectangle tilePos = new Rectangle((x * blockSize - viewX), (y * blockSize - viewY), blockSize, blockSize);
            #endregion

            #region Update
            if (globalUpdater == true)
            {
                if (blockGet(x, y, layerFG) > 0)
                {
                    blockUpdate(x, y, blockBG, blockFG, blockFG2);
                }

                //Destroy Deco
                if (block.GetTransparent(blockGet(x, y, layerFG)) && blockGet(x, y, layerFG2) != 0) blockSet(x, y, layerFG2, 0);
                if (block.GetTransparent(blockGet(x, y, layerBG)) && blockGet(x, y, layerBG2) != 0) blockSet(x, y, layerBG2, 0);
            }
            #endregion

            //Draw
            #region Draw backdrop
            if (globalBackdrop == true)
            {
                if (y > heightmapGet(x) + 16) spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBackdrop, tilePos, Color.White);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Draw background layer
            if (blockBG > 0)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlock, tilePos, new Rectangle(mathImgX(blockBG), mathImgY(blockBG), 32, 32), Color.White);
                if (blockBG2 > 0)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteDeco, tilePos, new Rectangle(mathImgX(blockBG2), mathImgY(blockBG2), 32, 32), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteHalfpixel, tilePos, Color.White);
            } 
            #endregion

            #region Draw foreground layer
            if (blockFG > 0)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlock, tilePos, new Rectangle(mathImgX(blockFG), mathImgY(blockFG), 32, 32), Color.White);
                if (blockFG2 > 0)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteDeco, tilePos, new Rectangle(mathImgX(blockFG2), mathImgY(blockFG2), 32, 32), Color.White);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Draw drop shadow
            if (blockBG > 0)
            {
                if (block.GetTransparent(blockFG) == true)
                {
                    int up = blockGet(x, y - 1, layerFG);
                    int down = blockGet(x, y + 1, layerFG);
                    int left = blockGet(x - 1, y, layerFG);
                    int right = blockGet(x + 1, y, layerFG);

                    if (up > 0) { if (block.GetTransparent(up) == false) spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlurTop, tilePos, Color.White); }
                    if (down > 0) { if (block.GetTransparent(down) == false) spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlurBottom, tilePos, Color.White); }
                    if (left > 0) { if (block.GetTransparent(left) == false) spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlurLeft, tilePos, Color.White); }
                    if (right > 0) { if (block.GetTransparent(right) == false) spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.spriteBlurRight, tilePos, Color.White); }
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }

    swblock.Stop(); debugTime.Add("Draw Blocks = " + swblock.Elapsed);
}
```

Basically this method does a for() loop that draws the four blocks layers (BG, BG2, FG, FG2), and a shadow effect on the uncovered background (drop shadow).

It is also measured by `StopWatch`.

This is the region of my draw method that calls the `DrawBlock()` above.

```
Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch(); sw2.Start();
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.PointClamp, s1, null, a);

//Draw blocks
if (globalDrawBlocks)
DrawBlock();

//Player
if (globalDrawPlayer) player.draw(spriteBatch);

spriteBatch.End();
sw2.Stop(); debugTime.Add("Draw Game = " + sw2.Elapsed);
```

The problem is that this causes obvious (and measured, using an FPS meter) lag. What's weird is that the stopwatch above tells me that the operation takes about 00.005ms, which is about 5 times faster than the amount of time it used to take, **but yet it still lags as if I had changed nothing**. Am I misinterpreting this measurement, or is it actually a problem?

*I cannot tell if this is a measurement or performance or interpretation issue!*

Comment: Eh? What do you mean by "it still lags"? Do you mean that your function is taking longer than the stopwatch says it does? If so, how do you know that?

Comment: What is the actual value of swblock.ElapsedMilliseconds?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @ChrisDunaway 5 milliseconds

Comment: If processing is superfast, then it must be the rendering that's causing the slowdown? Perhaps you could try a javascript DOM timer kind of thing to measure render time at the client.

Comment: @tnw I know because when i disable DrawBlock, it stops lagging.

Comment: @PaulZahra I have no idea what that is. I thought StopWatch meaured elapsed time, so shouldn't it not matter if it's rendering?

Comment: @JohnH Totally invalid edit. Changing tabbing/spacing in code is one thing, completely reorganizing his code is another. Don't do that. That's not his code any longer.

Comment: Does the Stopwatch *inside* `DrawBlock` give you 00.005ms, or is it the one *wrapping* `Begin`, `DrawBlock` and `End`?

Comment: @tnw What on earth are you on about?  I only changed indentation and removed the needless region lines in the last piece of code.

Comment: @BenjaminBeaulieu The one called swblock gives 00.005, the one outside thats wrapping the whole spritebatch as well gives 00.028.

Comment: Could you try `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` in the call to `Begin` and let us know if the measurement changes?

Comment: @BenjaminBeaulieu YES NOW THE MEASUREMENT IS CORRECT! But why does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [SpriteSortMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx) documentation.

It states that the `Deffered` mode waits for the call to `SpriteBatch.End` before drawing anything, so the call to `Draw` *queues* the draw action. The `Immediate` mode draws sprites as soon as a call to `Draw` is made.

Therefore, the `Stopwatch` doesn't give the correct measurement because nothing is actually drawn while it runs.